# Lambda data frame reference a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

How do I correctly reference another column value when using a Lambda in a pandas dataframe.

```
dfresult_tmp2['Retention_Rolling_temp'] = dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'].apply(lambda x: x if x['Count Billings']/4 < 0.20 else '')
```

The above code gives me this error.

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 

```
dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'].apply(
    lambda x: x if x['Count Billings'] / 4 < 0.20 else ''
)
```

You are using `pd.Series.apply` which is different than `pd.DataFrame.apply`.  In this case, you are iteratively passing a scalar value to the lambda.  So `some_scalar_x['Count Billings']` makes no sense.

Instead of telling you how to shoehorn your logic into an `apply`, I'll show you the vectorized versions instead

**Option 1**
*`pd.Series.where`*

```
dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'] = \
    dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'].where(
        dfresult_tmp2['Count Billings'] / 4 < .2, '')
```

**Option 2**
*`np.where`*

```
r = dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'].values
b = dfresult_tmp2['Count Billings'].values
dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'] = np.where(b / 4 < .2, r, '')
```

**Option 3**
*`apply`*
What you asked for but not what I'd recommend.

```
dfresult_tmp2['Retention_tmp'] = dfresult_tmp2.apply(
    lambda x: x['Retention_tmp'] if x['Count Billings'] / 4 < .2 else '',
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared I went with Option 1. For Option 3 I tried but was still getting an error. IndexError: ('Count Billings', 'occurred at index ISONAME')